# Passing Point parameter to SQL Server DB as geometry type

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I need to pass a Point value as a parameter to SQl Server DB.

But geometry is not a member in SqlDbType enumerator.

What solution can be used here? Should I split `Point.X` and `Point.Y` and pass as `floats`? And retrieve as floats and restore into a `Point`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct it as an [`SqlGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.aspx) in your C# code, then pass it as a [`SqlDbType.Udt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter (setting the `UdtTypeName` to `geometry`), and have it declared as a `geometry` parameter on the SQL side - it should all flow through correctly.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer. Why? That's just the only thing I managed to get so far. And for the sake of *working* tool, I just split the damn `Point` to take two `floats` for it's `.X` and `.Y`. So instead of having one Geometry column to record the point, I am constructing point with two columns for X, Y.